# PySpak and dataframe : Another way to show the type of one specific colum?

Tags: pyspark

I'm new with pYSPark and I'm struggling when I select one colum and I want to showh the type.

If I have a datagrame and want to show the types of all colums, this is what i do:

```
raw_df.printSchema()
```

If i want a specific column, i'm doig this but i'm sure we can do it faster:

```
new_df = raw_df.select( raw_df.annee)
new_df.printSchema()
```

Do i have to use select and store my colum in a new dataframe and use printchema()?
I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
raw_df.annee.printchema()
```

is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do i have to use select and store my colum in a new dataframe and use printchema()

Not necessarily - take a look at this code:

```py
raw_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2)], "id: int, val: int")
print(dict(raw_df.dtypes)["val"])

int
```

The `"val"` is of course the column name you want to query.